# Testing a Brunched app using Mocha and including shims

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, mocha.js, amd, brunch

I'm trying to test my Brunch+Backbone application using Mocha

A Mocha spec that `require`s various `devDependencies` works fine. A Mocha spec that `requires` my `devDependencies` and modules from my app works so long as I adjust the `NODE_PATH` variable

```
> NODE_PATH=./app mocha
:)
```

Failure occurs when my `require`d application module requires code that's been shimmed in from the `vendor/scripts` folder. These are simply unavailable to the `require` system and it's not clear to me how to get them into scope *before* loading my application code.

I can try using `brunch test` in newer versions, but that seems to be broken as of today. I get a bug complaining about how in `test.js` the function `helpers.findTestFiles` doesn't exist. That issue has been filed, but it leads me to believe that Brunch isn't broken, I'm just doing things incorrectly.

What is the *right* way to use Mocha to test a Brunch application using both AMD requires and shimmed vendor scripts (jQuery, Lodash, Backbone, Marionette)?

Comment: I have the (near-)exact same question. (Okay, I'm using Chaplin, not just raw backbone.)

Comment: Sadly I eventually gave up on Brunch because I could never get this working reliably. Fortunately, Mimosa (ha ha) seems to do what I needed quite well. Maybe it would work for you as well?